# "The process can not access the file '...' because it is being used by another process" when recreating temporary file for upload with FtpWebRequest

Tags: c#, asp.net, ftp, streamwriter, ftpwebrequest

I am uploading a file on FTP. At first it works fine, but as soon as I click the upload button second time it throws an error

> The process can not access the file '...' because it is being used by another process

The code is below

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filename, false)) //THIS LINE THROWS ERROR
{
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        sw.Write("Column1,Column2");
        sw.Write(sw.NewLine);

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            sw.Write(dr["Column1"].ToString());
            sw.Write(",");
            sw.Write(dr["Column2"].ToString());
            sw.Write(",");
        }
        sw.Close();
        sw.Dispose();
    }
    else
    {
        sw.Close();
        sw.Dispose();
    }
}
```

I am saving file in csv, can anyone please help me!! Why i am getting this error in second time?

Following is the code to upload on FTP

```
public void UploadToFTP()
{
     string fileName = "ReportName";
     string propfilename = Server.MapPath("~") + fileName + ".csv";

     string FtpUserid = null;
     string FtpPwd = null;
     string sourcePath = string.Empty;
     string destPath = string.Empty;
     string fName = string.Empty;
     FtpUserid = "abc";
     FtpPwd = "abc";

     fName = fileName + ".csv";

     destPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["destipath"].ToString();
     destPath = destPath.Insert(destPath.LastIndexOf("/") + 1, fName);

     FtpWebRequest requestFileExists = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(destPath);

     //GET DATA IN CSV
     UploadFTPCode(FtpUserid, FtpPwd, sourcePath, destPath, false);
 }

private void UploadFTPCode(string FtpUserid, string FtpPwd, string sourcePath, string destPath)
{
     FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(destPath);
     request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
     request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(FtpUserid, FtpPwd);
     request.Proxy = null;
     request.UseBinary = false;
     request.UsePassive = true;
     request.KeepAlive = false;
     request.Timeout = 500000;

     // Copy the contents of the file to the request stream.
     StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader(sourcePath);
     byte[] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
     sourceStream.Dispose();
     sourceStream.Close();
     request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

     Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
     requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
     requestStream.Flush();
     requestStream.Close();
     requestStream.Dispose();
     sourceStream.Close();
 }
```

Comment: It sounds like the file is  being accessed  by another process... You either have a lock on it somewhere else or somebody else does. Google how to see what process is locking a file, there should be lots of options for your os, e.g. Process monitor.

It could even be a virus scanner or similar.

Comment: Can you show the code that uploads this file to the FTP site? It is possible that the lock is created there.

Comment: What does your question have to do with FTP? There's no FTP in the code. Is this even [mcve]? If you loop only this code snippet twice, do you get the error? Or do we need some other code to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Code for uploading on FTP added, @Steve

Comment: There' nothing wrong with this code (apart from being inefficient, redundant and unsafe) - If I run it twice in a loop, all works right - Show us [mcve].

Comment: Why do you even create the file? Why don't you write the data directly to the `request.GetRequestStream()`?

Comment: Almost always, the error message is a lie, and it is in fact your own code holding a reference to the file (exception - some poorly behaving anti-virus products can sometimes hold locks on files for extended periods). It *looks* like you're disposing of all of the objects referencing the file (although it would be more assured if you just adopted `using` statements rather than manually `Dispose`ing them), so look for surrounding code that makes use of the same path.

Answer (score -1):

Try calling garbage collection after you dispose the file like this:

```
GC.Collect();
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, but still the same issue. Any other work around?

Answer (score -1):

There's nothing wrong with your code (apart from being inefficient, redundant and unsafe) - If I run it twice in a loop, all works right.

Though I do not see a point of creating a supposedly temporary file, just for the upload. Write the data directly to the upload/request stream.

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(destUrl);
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
request.Proxy = null;
request.UseBinary = false;
request.UsePassive = true;
request.KeepAlive = false;
request.Timeout = 500000;

using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(requestStream))
{
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        sw.Write("Column1,Column2");
        sw.Write(sw.NewLine);

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            sw.Write(dr["Column1"].ToString());
            sw.Write(",");
            sw.Write(dr["Column2"].ToString());
            sw.Write(",");
        }
    }
}
```

---

*Also note that your CSV creating code does not look right either (you do not terminate the lines). It should be like:*

```
sw.WriteLine("Column1,Column2");

foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    sw.WriteLine(dr["Column1"].ToString() + "," + dr["Column2"].ToString());
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate about the termination of line? Also the code works good in local but when i deploy it on my server, then its giving error (for the second click).

Comment: How can we help you, if you do not tell us what is the "error"? + Line termination: I have edited my answer.

Comment: if i run it on local, it works good no matter how many times i upload but it gives problem when i deploy the code on server. :( may be there's some silly thing i am missing in the code!

Comment: We know that. You have told us already! **What error/problems?**